# Should there be any punctuation marks in this sentence?

Tags: punctuation

other than full stop.

The sentence is ***"Sample B must be isolated."*** Is it missing a comma or a hyphen between the words ***Sample*** and ***B***?

Answer (score 2):

I can see no reason to punctuate any further.

> Chef Ramsay is in the kitchen.
>
> Captain Kirk is on the bridge.
>
> HMS Victory must be repaired urgently.
>
> Sample B must be isolated.

They're all the same.

**Afterthought**

If 'Sample-B' is the *name* of the sample rather than just 'B', then maybe yes.

**Example**

*"We placed Sample-B in Room-B."*

*"Why?"*

*"Because Sample-B must be isolated."*

In this case we have to distinguish between Sample-B and Room-B so we can't just say 'B'.